# Where is the default outputcache class?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, outputcache

The default outputcache provider is specified as "AspNetInternalProvider" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228124.aspx).  But where does this class exist?  I can't find it and I would like to inspect some of its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK I may have found which class they use under the hood: System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)

Comment: I believe its true. There is no class AspNetInternalProvider, searched in Reflector

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4, the default cache implementation is System.Web.Caching.CacheInternal.  Looking in reflector, that class has no dependencies on System.Runtime.Caching and therefore there are no dependencies on System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.